# Updating a column from a calculated field using UPDATE, SUM & EXTRACT functions

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, sql-update

I want to update the 'duration_s' column (numeric), so I can obtain the duration in minutes & hours and also obtain velocity, using the given distance traveled.

but first I need to transform ride_length (schema - time) into an integer

so I tried, but I am stuck.  this is the query I tried to write:

```
WITH calc AS (
      SELECT 
      SUM((EXTRACT(HOUR FROM ride_length)*3600)+(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM ride_length)*60)+EXTRACT(SECOND FROM ride_length)) AS seconds
      FROM `fresh-ocean-357202.Cyclistic.Cyclistic_yearly`
)
UPDATE `fresh-ocean-357202.Cyclistic.Cyclistic_yearly`
SET duration_s = calc.seconds
WHERE TRUE
```

these field names have NULL are set as NUMERIC as its data type

[image: these are the columns that Im working on]

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Rather, copy and paste the SQL query in your question. http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode Also, the issue you describe in your question is quite clear, but the title is not.

Comment: already edited sir. this is my first time using stack overflow ^^

Answer (score 0):

I already got it. Instead of doing this:

```
UPDATE `fresh-ocean-357202.Cyclistic.Cyclistic_yearly` 
SET duration_s = SUM((EXTRACT(HOUR FROM ride_length)*3600)+(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM ride_length)*60)+EXTRACT(SECOND FROM ride_length))
WHERE TRUE
```

I did this:

```
UPDATE `fresh-ocean-357202.Cyclistic.Cyclistic_yearly` 
SET duration_s = (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM ride_length)*3600)+(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM ride_length)*60)+EXTRACT(SECOND FROM ride_length)
WHERE TRUE
```

I just removed the SUM function into the SET function